# Linq2SQL working on Console Applicaton, but not working on Windows Service

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, windows-services

It was difficult to choose correct title, but here is the problem:

I've an application with simple logic, that gets data from TFS, iterates over "items" and updates local DB with these "items". Here is a code snippet for updating the row:

```
using (ResultDBDataContext local_db= new ResultDBDataContext())
{
DBTestResult dbRes = local_db.DBTestResults.getByPrimaryKey(args_supplied);
if (dbRes == null) {
  dbRes = new DBTestResult(){//set properties}
  local_db.DBTestResults.InsertOnSubmit(dbRes);
}
else{
  dbRes.isDirty = true;
  dbRes.otherPropertis = set_to_some_values;
}
local_db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

This is working in Windows Console program (imported >100K rows like this), which proves that logic is correct. But when I put same logic to Windows Service (against same data), after a while (<2K rows) I get an SQL exception saying "can't insert duplicate key into the table". Note that I do SubmitChanges() after updating/inserting **each row**

I think this is somehow related on the followings, but not able to find out the reasons:

- How Windows Services handle  DB connectios. (Do they pool? Do they cache data? etc.)
- Linq2SQL Dataconext handling it's update objects. (What properties of Linq2SQL Datacontext make it behave differently under Windows Services?)

Any ideas/suggestions/links/tutorials/articles on how to resolve this issue or on finding out more information about the problem are greatly welcome.

Thanks.

**Update**: The data coming from TFS, may violate the database's primary key constraint - but since I'm inserting/updating one row at a time and committing changes, the last entry for the same primary key will reside in database.

Comment: Have you run in the login of the console user when in the windows service? Does it have the same behaviour?

Comment: Yes, both are/were run with the same credentials (if you are asking this)

Comment: Assuming there's indeed something wrong with the SQL you might find this MSDN article useful for debugging **[How to: Display Generated SQL (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx)**

Comment: Can you post the code for insertNewResult and updateDbRes?

Comment: Added code for inserting and updating - I doubt that this is the problem, since it's running ok as a Console ApPplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas/suggestions/links/tutorials/articles on how to resolve this issue or on finding out more information about the problem are greatly welcome.

This sounds to me like it's not a problem with the service side of the code.

I think you need to log/inspect this error behaviour further - just try logging which primary key(s) this is occurring for - it may be that you'll notice some error in your getByPrimaryKey implementation that way.

Also check that your service is single threaded - i.e. that there can't be two instances executing simultaneously - that could certainly lead to an error.

Comment: If there was a problem in Logic, it would hit same exception in Console application.  Actually I log Exception and which row violated the constraint. When it checks DB, a row does NOT Exist, when it tries to insert the row is already there. If there were several instances of the service running, I would expect same kind of problems.Is there a way to control service thread count etc. ? I'm investigating it currently. Thank you for good idea.

Comment: BTW, I'm not creating threads within the service. I was just wondering may be Windows Service "container" somehow does that for performance reasons.

Comment: One other thought - there aren't any other unique keys defined, are there?

Comment: So my service was calling a job every time interval, making use of Timer. It turned out that when job duration is longer the Timer interval, Timer expires and starts a new job (not sure whether as a separate thread, or re-uses same thread) - so this resulted in this ugly, difficult to debug concurrency problem. So now I'm disabling Timer, while the job is being done - so basically waiting "wantedSeconds" after the job is done.

Answer (score 0):

What is triggering your service to start it's operation? It sounds like your process is runnning a second time which is causing your data to be processed twice rather than once when running it as a console application.

For example, if you are using the FileSystemWatcher to let you know when new files arrive to process, the watcher will fire multiple events as the file is created, and added to (updated).

Comment: It's polling service, it's triggered after couple of minutes. But (1) these exceptions are occurring on the first run , (2) Even if it was processing data several times, I'm checking the entry in DB, insert only if not exist, otherwise update.So this should NOT be a problem